# Magento 2. How to upload images to pub/media

Tags: magento2, admin, image-upload, fieldsets

**Problem**

I have a `$fieldset`. What arguments should I give to `->addField` method to create an input field, that loads image to `$_FILES`?

**What was done**

For now I have an input field.

[image]

Created by

```
 $fieldset->addField('image',
            'image',
            [
                'title' => __('Image'),
                'label' => __('Image'),
                'name' => 'image',
                'note' => 'Allow image type: jpg, jpeg, gif, png',
            ]
        );
```

But the `$_FILES` **is empty**, when I checking it in controller `execute()` method.

**Additional information**

`$fieldset` arguments was taken from [this example](http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-backend-upload-image-coming-from-edit-form).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to file **app/code/Vendor/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Modulename/Edit/Form.php**

there is **'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'**

```
 $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => ['id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]
        );
```